# Is this question about paint composition on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm wondering if this question is on topic for Arts & Crafts or not: https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/2559/30

> We all know most commonly known paints are CMY(k) because they are
>   "subtractive". But the RGB color wheel is additive, meaning it EMITS
>   far more light, however RGB color schemes that you can view on your
>   old CRT or even LCD/LED TV are much sharper, vivid and color-correct.
>   The deep blacks and bright whites are also piercing to the eye. Even
>   the sun is RGB!
>
> My question is if we were to somehow make certain pigment based paints
>   much less molecularly dense without losing the "thickness" of it...
>   would we be able to paint in RGB? There are already LED printers that
>   literally PRINT in RGB onto special photosensitive paper but as I said
>   they are not ink based. what about the possibility of a special type
>   of RGB paint that when all 3 colors are mixed produce white instead of
>   black? I think it's an interesting idea but I do not know of any such
>   paint in existence.

**Is this a suitable fit?** While it isn't about *making* an art/craft, it is (maybe) about *producing a medium/material* to use in an art/craft. On the other hand, it may be getting more into color theory and physics than we are suited to answer (in which case migration to Physics may be a reasonable solution).

Comment: As an aside, it is safe to say that this question was never asked on Physics, he has no network profile for the site and his top network rep is 4, so not an experienced user of the platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asking about the possibility is really a question of physics or chemistry, perhaps even both. Asking about how to use such a paint, were it to exist, would make more sense here.

At the end of the day, though, creating a permanent application of light emitting paint seems unlikely, to be generous. However, to put more substance behind that would require a physics and chemistry lesson that has low value here.

Comment: Right. The question is essentially asking how to create a new type of matter that somehow reflects more light as more of the material is mixed in, without putting off energy that eats through or combusts your painting material & surface. That's way beyond the scope of applied, hands-on arts & crafts.